# How to make a plane keep still in arview?

Tags: swift, arkit, face-detection, realitykit

ace tracking with ARKit, in my case, I added a mask node to the ARSCNView as the following code:

```
let planeNode = SCNNode()
planeNode.geometry = SCNPlane(width: 10,height: 10)
planeNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = .red
planeNode.position.z = -5     // 5 meters away
```

faceTrackingSceneView.pointOfView?.addChildNode(planeNode)

and it works well, the camera stream filled with the red color, just keep the head(model) showing.

For some other reason, I'd like to change the ARSCNView to ARView, so I tried as the above code like this:

```
let bgAnchor = try! Experience.loadBg()
bgAnchor.transform.translation = [0,0,-5]

let resource = MeshResource.generatePlane(width: 10, height: 10)
let material = UnlitMaterial(color: .red) 
let palne = ModelEntity(mesh:resource,materials: [material] )
bgAnchor.addChild(palne)
```

the red background shows and only the head shows. But when i move my head(phone), the red background moved too, so, my question is, is there anyway that make the red background keep still? or maybe something wrong with me?